# Relative URL in [ngStyle]

Tags: css, angular, angular2-pipe

Trying to us a relative URL to set the background-image in a div. At the moment I'm trying to use a pipe:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + banner + ')'}"></div>
```

A2 renders this in the markup:

```
<div _ngcontent-c2="" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="background-image: url(http://localhost:8080/assets/raster/banners/banner-background-02-800x300.png);">
</div>
```

I've tried using a pipe:

```
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({name: 'safeHtml'})
export class SafeHtml {
  constructor(private sanitizer:DomSanitizer){}

  transform(html) {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
  }
}
```

And this update in the markup:

```
  <div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + banner | safeHtml + ')'}">
  </div>
```

Which results in this error in the console:

```
"Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Missing expected } at column 49 in [{'background-image': 'url(' + banner | safeHtml + ')'}] in ng:///AppModule/AppBannerComponent.html@0:5 (\"<div [ERROR ->][ngStyle]=\"{'background-image': 'url(' + banner | safeHtml + ')'}\">
</div>\"): ng:///AppModule/AppBannerComponent.html@0:5"
```

I've tried wrapping the binding and pipe like so:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(' + ( banner | safeHtml ) + ')'}">
</div>
```

But get this in the render:

```
<div _ngcontent-c2="" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]"></div>
```

Trying to achieve this:

```
<div _ngcontent-c2="" *ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]"* style="background-image: url(/assets/raster/banners/banner-background-02-800x300.png);">
</div> <!-- or whatever ng-reflect-ng-style would be if the binding and piping are correct -->
```

Comment: Have you tried to wrap `banner | safeHtml` like this: `(banner | safeHtml)`? it looks like your problem is a concatenation one, because the error occurs in template parsing.

Comment: I thought I had, but I will double-check.

Comment: I checked again and I did try that, but it somehow got hidden in this post. I've fixed that and updated the post.

Comment: @Eric Did you ever resolve this? I am the exact same issue!

Comment: @TigerBear I know it's been a while, but I just posted an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, this a bit late answer but I just faced this today and solved by adding the HTML Entity Definitions `&quot;` to the `css` `url` parameter, like:

`'url(&quot;'+ banner | safeHtml +'&quot;)'`

So:

```
<div 
    [ngStyle]="{'background-image': 'url(&quot;'+ banner | safeHtml +'&quot;)'}">
  </div>
```

you also can use `backgroundImage` :

`[ngStyle]="{backgroundImage: 'url(&quot;'+ banner | safeHtml +'&quot;)'}"`

hope it helps...